# Parsing HTTP request JSON body in scala with play

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using Scala with Play and looking for a cleaner way to write POST request handler below:

```
  def create = Action.async { request => {
    request.body.asJson match {
      case Some(x) => x.validate[UserDto] match {
        case c: JsSuccess[UserDto] => doActualWork(c.get)
        case e: JsError => Future.successful(BadRequest(""))
      }
      case None => Future.successful(BadRequest(""))
    }
  }
  }
```

Problems:

1. Many lines required for *only* parsing JSON object UserDto (which is a common procedure)
2. Highly nested (poor readability)

Comment: You can use their json body parser to cut down some noise. You would still want to do some validation though that the json is thr type you want. You can also abstract it further but im on my phone so i cant put up the code just yet of one way i have done it in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json body parser. Now body of the request contains json automatically and you can get rid of outer pattern match.

```
def create = Action.async(parse.json) {
    _.body.validate[UserDto] match {
      case JsSuccess(value, _) => doActualWork(value)
      case _ => Future.successful(BadRequest("bad json body"))
    }
  }
```

It is advisable to say what went wrong here instead of saying `bad json body`

Comment: You can make it even shorter: `def create = Action.async(parse.json[UserDto]) { request => doActualWork(request.body) }`

Answer (score 3):

The cleaner way would involve using a **Play body parser**.

```
def create = Action.async(parse.json[UserDto]) { request =>
  doActualWork(request.body)
}
```

The json body parser will validate that the request has a Content-Type of `application/json`, and send back a `415 Unsupported Media Type` response if the request doesn’t meet that expectation. Hence you don’t need to check again in your action code.

***Note:*** if your client is not sending the Content-Type you might try using:

`parse.tolerantJson` - this is a bit more relaxed

---

This works because the `Action` trait is actually defined as:

```
trait Action[A] extends (Request[A] => Result) {
  def parser: BodyParser[A]
}
```